# Etheruem Wallet: Can't Switch Back To Main Network

Tags: wallets, network

When I open my Ethereum Wallet, I'm automatically assigned to Test-Net. I can switch to a private network I created. Then I have the option to go back to the Main network, from the menu options, but when I do so, I'm automatically placed in Test-Net. Any ideas how to get back to Main?